# When claiming under Manufacturer's warranty, how can Plaintiff prove never breaching Manufacturer's proper care and use instructions?

Tags: canada, consumer-protection

Many non-stick products are sold with a limited lifetime warranty, e.g. for their NONstickiness. **Presume that a consumer has perfectly followed**, [e.g., manufacturer's proper care and use instructions](https://www.zwilling.com/us/about-us/use-care/article-use-care-cookware.html).

I read about this class action, but I cannot find it on CanLII. But when Consumer pleaded a breach of this lifetime warranty, Defendant Manufacturer alleged that Plaintiff breached Manufacturer's instructions. Upon inspection of Plaintiff's used product, Defendant allegedly found that Plaintiff negligently either used its non-stick cookware over high heat, AND/OR held acidic foods in the pan, AND/OR left food scraps to dry on the pan, AND/OR scratched the NONstick coating with metal utensils and/or scouring agents and/or abrasive sponges, AND/OR held acidic foods in the pan. As an example, see this [blog post](https://www.oxo.com/blog/cooking-and-baking/how-to-use-non-stick-pan).

As alternative pleading, Defendant [put Plaintiff to strict proof](https://burnetteshutt.law/quit-demanding-strict-proof-answers-not-thing/) that Plaintiff fulfilled manufacturer's instructions.

##### On a balance of probabilities, how can Plaintiff gainsay Defendant, and [prove this kind of negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proving_a_negative) that Plaintiff never "used its non-stick cookware over high heat AND/OR" etc...? Obviously, Plaintiff cannot realistically record continuous 24/7 video footage of the pan, since the time of purchase and contract formation!

Some examples are below:

- [Cuisinart's NONstick Hard-Anodized
  Skillet](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/384543335404)
- [T-fal's Intuition 26 cm
  Frypan](https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca/intuition-frypan-26-cm/p/20972396_EA)
- [Meyer Confederation's Everyday
  Pan](https://www.facebook.com/MeyerCanada/photos/a.516313132052640/1241840016166611/?type=3&paipv=0&eav=Afay2z5XFASfHsRJxP9aRfB4Ws-HIbD1lloGUyTX7YmxR7jzSh73DZt_SN3Pq1mBtLY&_rdr)

Comment: Your link for "strict proof" seems to be saying that the defendant is not actually required to give strict proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [semper necessitas probandi incumbit ei qui agit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burden_of_proof_(law))

Roughly “she who asserts must prove.” The manufacturer is asserting actions by the consumer - the manufacturer has to prove they happened, the consumer does not have to prove they didn’t.